Mocking API service in blazemeter with generic route param
I am trying to mock my API service in blazemeter. The request looks like
users/{id} which is a GET call and the mock service should accept anything as id. Regardless of what id is passed in the route, the response should be same.
I tried to add below in request matcher but no luck.

users/{id}
users/*
users/${id}
users/.*

No luck. Please help
